# Removing Characters from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry - I'm a complete novice, so any help greatly appreciated.

I have about 30,000 entries in a column (texty3) in a mysql database that need to have certain characters/words removed:

Specifically,

Any words shorter than 3 characters. 
Any non-capilised words. 
Anything non-alphanumeric.

I was was wondering if there was a mysql command for this?

I had someone write a script for future uploads via php that looks like this,

```
function getmtext($str) {
    $text = '';
    $words = str_word_count($str, 1);
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if ($word[0] >= 'A' && $word[0] <= 'Z') 
            if (strlen($word)>3) 
                $text .= $word.' ';
    }
    return $text;
}
```

But I don't know how to edit entries that already exist.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I think you would have to write a PHP Script to batch process all your entries in the Database, MySQL doesn't have functions built in to do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that same script to update the entries in your SQL, there's no way (that I'm aware of) to do as you requested using purely SQL.

That said you can retrieve the data from the database (using mysql functions), modify the information and return it to the database.

For arguments sake if you had the database locally, named test with no password logging in as root you could use something like:

```
function getmtext($str) {
    $text = '';
    $words = str_word_count($str, 1);
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if ($word[0] >= 'A' && $word[0] <= 'Z') 
        if (strlen($word)>3) 
            $text .= $word.' ';
    }
    return $text;
}

//set the database parameters
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "";
$dbName = "test";

//create the database connection
$dbConn = mysql_connect ($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die ('MySQL connect failed. ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbName) or die('Cannot select database. ' . mysql_error());

//sql to get all texty3 rows from table
$sql = "select id, texty3 from testtable";
$query = mysql_query($sql); //run the sql
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { //loop through each row
     $rowId = $result['id'];
     $text = $result['texty3'];
     $cleansedText = getmtext($text);
     mysql_query("update testtable set texty3 = '$cleansedText' where id = '$rowId';");
}
```

This would go through the database and use that function to remove all words that don't match the parameters defined in the function. (Sorry I don't have the ability to check this code at the minute but it should be correct or at least close)